# Orden «vue» no encontrada

Tags: nodejs

Instale Nodejs en Ubuntu 18.04, reconoce la instalacion *nodejs -v* y *npm -v*, pero, al ejecutar *vue --version* recibo el mensaje:

```
Orden «vue» no encontrada. Quizá quiso decir:

  la orden «vpe» del paquete deb «texlive-latex-extra»

Pruebe con: sudo apt install <nombre del paquete deb>
```

Comment: ¿Tratabas de instalar vue-cli?

Comment: Lo instalaste de esta manera: ```sudo yarn global add @vue/cli``` o ```sudo npm install -g @vue/cli``` ?

Comment: Sí y aparece que se instalo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre esta respuesta que quizás te ayude.

[https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/275#issuecomment-269215870][1]

En resumen, lo que tratan de decir es quizá debas reinstalar el npm.

1. Back up your computer.
2. On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.npm-global
   ```
3. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   ```
   npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
   ```
4. In your preferred text editor, open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

   ```
   export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
   ```
5. On the command line, update your system variables:

   ```
   source ~/.profile
   ```
6. To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo:

   ```
   npm install -g jshint
   ```

Instead of steps 2-4, you can use the corresponding ENV variable (e.g. if you don’t want to modify ~/.profile):

```
    NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
```